# Why is basemap plotting this latitude and longitude off land when I know it to be on land?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm creating a scatter plot on top of a map of NSW, Australia in basemap and the location of a radar (which i know to be lon=151.2095, lat=-33.7008) is plotted as being in the ocean when it's actually inland. Why is this happening?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_gauges_on_map():

    lon_0, lat_0 = 151.2095, -33.7008
    width = 1000000
    m = Basemap(width=width,height=width,projection='aeqd',
            lat_0=lat_0,lon_0=lon_0)
    # fill background.
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='dodgerblue')
    # draw coasts and fill continents.
    m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
    m.fillcontinents(color='peru',lake_color='dodgerblue')
    # draw a black dot at the radar.
    xpt, ypt = m(lon_0, lat_0)
    m.plot([xpt],[ypt],'ko')
    # draw the title.
    plt.title('Terrey Hills Radar')
    plt.show()

plot_gauges_on_map()
```

Comment: Default resolution of coastlnes is terrible. Add `resolution="i"` to Basemap() and get what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the `resolution` of the map boundary database to use, hence, the crude database is in effect. To get proper resolution in your case, the option `resolution="i"` should be added in Basemap() statement, where "i" stands for intermediate. Possible resolutions are:- c(crude, the default), l(low), i, h(high) and f(full). The output of your plot will look like the following.

[image]